# read mifare card block and compare part of its block with some text

Tags: c++, arduino, nfc, mifare

I'm reading a Mifare card block using RC522, I wrote "RhytonUser001" in one block.

Arduino reads it in this way:

```
byte readbackblock[18];//This array is used for reading out a block. The MIFARE_Read method requires a buffer that is at least 18 bytes to hold the 16 bytes of a block.

for (int j=0 ; j<16 ; j++) //print the block contents
{
    char c = readbackblock[j];
    lcd.print(c);
}
```

readbackblock[j] is an ascii character that returns from card.
I need to convert it to its real Characters, then convert it to String because i want to split that string.

I also tried this (without split):

```
     char d = readbackblock[0] + readbackblock[1] + readbackblock[2] + readbackblock[3] + readbackblock[4] + readbackblock[5];
     if(d == "Rhyton"){
      digitalWrite(7, HIGH);
     } else {
      digitalWrite(6, HIGH); // always this happens
     }
```

**UPDATE:**
example:
in above code please just think:
readbackblock[j] = 082 104 121 116 111 110 085 115 101 114 048 048 049
i can get it and convert it to char so it's become: RhytonUser001
then i want to split it `String sth = split(***, 'User');`
and get `sth[0]` and compare it with Rhyton to check if it is Rhyton or not
but when i try to do this i get an error.
based on information given in [this link](https://processing.org/reference/split_.html) I can not split char(because it is not string). So how can I compare readbackblock[j] with Rhyton or any other texts?

Comment: ASCII character is the most human readable as it can be.

Comment: BTW `readbackblock[j];` doesn't do anything, just as `42;` doesn't do anything. Please post real code.

Comment: If its in ASCII then its already in human readable form, just add a '\0' terminator to the end of the array then you can print it.

Comment: @SPlatten for example i need to convert 65 to A to display in LCD then i need to convert it to string to split and see is Rhyton exist or not!

Comment: Question Edited and Updated...

Comment: 'A' == 65. Please explain what doesn't work with your code

Comment: @manuell thanks for your attention, please look at my code, first: i want to get "RhytonUser001" completely in a variable like "c", then i want to split it to check if "Rhyton" exist in that or not.  
this code will print character by character in the lcd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a `String` object by concatenating the 16 characters.

```
String strBlock = "";
for (int j=0 ; j<16 ; j++) //print the block contents
{
    char c = readbackblock[j];
    lcd.print(c);
    strBlock += c;
}
```

Then, you could use `substring` to extract various part.

```
String strFirst6 = strBlock.substring( 0, 6 );
if ( strFirst6 == "Rhyton" ) {
    ...
```

Be cautious with the actual length of the string. It's undefined behavior if you try to read past the end. The above code suppose that none of the 16 characters will be 0.

Comment: thank you, it worked, now i need to split it in this way  
String sth = split(strBlock , 'User');